# validation always return false even if it is correct. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am validating form. It correctly validates all the field but when I enter correct data in text fields then still it does not process the data and return `everything wrong` whereas I want to it to return `everything correct`

Here is my js code

```
var url, container, form,
    View = {
        init: function () {
            container     = $('.container');
            $(document).on('submit', '#form', View.findView);
        },

        loadViews: function (view, flag, e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var search = $('.search');

            if( flag ) {
                if ( View.validation.emptyFieldsValidation() == true ) {
                    console.log('everything correct');
                } else {
                    console.log('everything incorrect');
                }
            }
            return false;
        },

        validation: {
            emptyFieldsValidation: function () {
                var inputs, field;

                $('#form input').each(function (i, el) {
                    inputs = $(this);
                    if ( inputs.val() == '' ) {
                        inputs.css('border', '1px solid red');
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        inputs.css('border', '1px solid #ccc');
                        if (inputs.hasClass('from')) {
                            console.log('from');
                            if (View.validation.validateAddress(inputs.val())) {
                                console.log('from correct address');
                                return true;
                            }
                            else {
                                inputs.css('border', '1px solid red');
                                console.log('from incorrect address');
                                //return false;
                            }
                        }
                        if (inputs.hasClass('to')) {
                            console.log('to');
                            if (View.validation.validateAddress(inputs.val())) {
                                console.log('to correct address');
                                //return true;
                            }
                            else {
                                inputs.css('border', '1px solid red');
                                console.log('to incorrect address');
                                //return false;
                            }
                        }
                        if (inputs.hasClass('time')) {
                            if (View.validation.validateForNumber(inputs.val())) {
                                console.log('time correct');
                                //return true;
                            }
                            else {
                                inputs.css('border', '1px solid red');
                                console.log('time incorrect');
                                //return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            },

            validateAddress: function (val) {
                var streetregex = /^[\w+\s]+\d+,\s*[\s\w]+$/;
                if (streetregex.test(val)) return true;
                else return false;
            },

            validateForNumber: function (val) {
                if (!isNaN(val)) return true;
                else return false;
            }
        }
    };

View.init();
```

​
here is my html code

```
<section class="search">
<form id="form" action="">
    <section>
        <input type="text" name="from" class="from address" id="addressone" placeholder="From">
    </section>
    <section>
        <input type="text" name="to" class="to address" id="addresstwo" placeholder="To">
    </section>
    <section>
        <label>Time</label>
        <input type="text" name="hrs" placeholder="Hours" class="t1 time">
        <span>:</span>
        <input type="text" name="mins" placeholder="Mins" class="t1 time">
        <button class="button">Search</button>
    </section>
</form>
</section>
```

**Update**

I am getting this output in my console

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to miss the fact that your `emptyFieldsValidation` function will always `return false`, as all the other `return` statements in its body are actually parts of 'iterator' function. Speaking of the latter, note that `return false` in `$.each` callback will stop the iteration.

One possible way out of it is replacing all these `return false` statements in the iterator function with filling the array of validation errors instead. Then (after `$.each` line) you could check for its length (or just do `return !!errors.length`). For example:

```
emptyFieldsValidation: function () {
  var errors = [];
  ...
  $('#form input').each(function() {
    if (! someValidationCheck) { 
      errors.push(someValidationAttribute);  
    }
  });
  ...
  return !!errors.length;
```

Comment: Could you please give me some code so that I could use it in my solution. Thanks

Comment: @al0neevenings Updated the answer with example.

Comment: What does that `!!` mean in return?

Comment: !! converts its argument to `boolean`. `array.length` is int (`Number`, strictly speaking), but you probably don't need to know the exact number of errors, you just need to know whether there are any. It's not needed, but it gives a hint of what's going on here.